# Bootstrap Modals Inside bootstrap-select plugin

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **[bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)** plugin as my Drop down menu.

I was trying to add bootstrap Modal one one of the options of that dropdown. 
example:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="false" >
       <option>Team Lead</option>
       <option>Juniour Employee</option>
       <option>Intern</option>
       <option>Director</option>
       <option role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seg-Seniority">Add/Edit Categories..</option>

 </select>
```

But it seems like when I click on the ADD/EDIT where modal is called is not coming. Is this possible to make if ADD/EDIT is clicked the popup will come?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way you can do is by `change` method for select.

I have this as my option `<option data-dismiss="true" data-target="#confirm">Hide modal</option>`

This is my script

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function () {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected");
    // this hides a modal
    if (selectedOption.data('dismiss')) {
        $(selectedOption.data('target')).modal('hide');
    }
    // this shows a modal
    if( selectedOption.data('modal') ){
        $(selectedOption.data('target')).modal('show');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/3kgbG/321/)

Hope this helps

Comment: This is what I was looking for :) you save my day. Lot's of blessings for you.

Comment: @Raihan: also if you think it answers the question please mark it as answered so that other people can find it useful too. Thanks